# Layering projects on top of each other with git

Tags: linux, git, shell

**Let there be:**

There are different repositories repoA, repoB and repoC each respecting the same directory layout principles, which are to be merged onto a third repoM's working directory (the "master" project).

repoM has an atypical setup (--work-dir and --git-dir are sepparate). repo[A-C] are cloned as bare, and they are set as `core.bare = false` and `core.worktree=<--work-dir-of-repoM>`.

**The requirements:**

I need to always have an overview over the history of all files in repoM's work-dir, which could have stemmed from repo[A-C]. With this approach, I lose all that information.

**Alternative:**

I've been thinking about using git-subtree instead (`git version 1.7.11.2`, so it's already built-in), leaving repo[A-C] bare, and then

- `git pull -s subtree`, **or**
- `git subtree ...`

With the subtree pull strategy, I lose the history on a merge conflict (`git blame` says so).

I've never used subtree before, but from my understanding it's not possible to merge files from repo[A-C] into repoM's work-dir, those files must be put into a subdirectory of repo[A-C]. This is definitely not what I need. **Why?** Because of the following ...

**Problem statement:**

You have different git repositories each containing different sets of files, usually configuration files and some shell scripts. You want to put everything in the `$HOME` (which is `<--work-dir-of-repoM>`) directory from all those repositories. You should be able to see at all time where each file comes from, edit, commit and push changes to each one's `origin`. You've guessed it, it something like [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/), but generalized for any kind of configuration of any program, not just *vim bundles*. If a conflict occures, one should be able to track down which two authors of the same file need to get in touch with each other and make up a deal (if one needs to be made).

This is for an open-source project I'm trying to get a prototype working, so any help is highly appreciated. Also ideas about already existing projects which do this in a similar manner are highly appreciated.

**Note:** the "master directory" does not necessarily have to be `$HOME`, I've used it as a possible hint on the kind of problem this could solve.

Comment: Why the complexity of subtree? Why not treat this the way you would any [integration manager](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow) workflow?

Comment: @Christopher I've just listed the things I've tried, given the requirements exposed. How would your proposal meet those requirements?

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure I understand your requirements, hence my question. It sounds like you've got three repos which fork, in minor ways, a blessed repository that should contain all the changes from each of the three. Would that be accurate or is there some complexity to it I'm not seeing (entirely possible)?

Comment: Imagine a `repoA/.vimrc` with one set of configuration data, and among those, precisely one line `set nocompatible`.Then the other repo with completely different data, one of the files being also `repoB/.vimrc` and precisely one line `set compatible`.Imagine I want to be able to take those files and use them. Both. Of course there will be a conflict,I'll solve it. But I want to be able to `git blame ~/.vimrc` at any time and to be able to track down the entire history and all other "possibilities" that other repos have provided throughout the time.Does it make sense, in the context of `$HOME`?

Comment: And all this in a homogenous history tree, so as little hacking as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your "master project"?

Comment: I must quote myself on this one: *those files must be put into a subdirectory of repo[A-C]. This is definitely not what I need.*

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement they _must_ share the same root directory?  Are all repositories something you control or are they _independent_ projects?

Comment: Yes, it's an absolute requirement. It's the very thing that this arragement must do. They are somehow independent, but somehow they do respect a certain directory layout, thus it can come to conflicts. Are you a linux user? If you were, you'd understand what it's about from the **Problem statement**.

Comment: I am - and I do see where there will be an issue sharing a common directory layout just by the nature of the working directory being shared across repos and the problems of tracking history and changes due to this fact.

Comment: So having the master project having the cross-cutting bits and glue of your project (configuration, scripts, et al.) and using submodules for the rest is out of the question?

Comment: By using submodules? A submodule must reside inside a repoM's subdirectory, it can't live directly under `repoM/`, which is what is desired... Addendum: oh well, I don't want to pollute the $HOME directory with "garbage" (the actual tracked files inside the subdirs, that is)